# Finding an item in a database in php

Tags: php, mysql

Using a combination of PHP and MySQL, let's say I have a database with some tables. I have a page (php or html) which allows a user to enter a string; this will search a specific table for their input and return information on the entry if it exists, and tell them nothing could be found otherwise. So more specifically, if I had a table titled `zookeepers` which had a row `name` and I wanted a page where the user is prompted to enter a name and return whether there was a zookeeper with that name or not and if so output their information, what would the code look like for that?

I'm pretty sure what I want is:

```
SELECT * FROM zookeepers WHERE name = $variable
```

as far as the query goes, but I'm not sure beyond that.

Comment: That query is open for a SQL injection.

Comment: have u tried any code?

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE keywork in your query 
as name can be same for multiple rows

change

```
 SELECT * FROM zookeepers WHERE name = $variable
```

to

```
$select="SELECT * FROM zookeepers WHERE name LIKE '%$variable%'";
```

Comment: This is open for a sql injection mate.

Comment: @Daan could you give an example on how we can inject into this query??

Comment: @Ye.  $variable = `"\''; DROP TABLE users; --"`